# Determining the resistivity of gold and copper alloy

Tags: electrical-resistance

Say we got an alloy made of $90$% Au and $10$%Cu. The atomic mass of gold is $$A_{Au}=197g/mole$$ and of copper $$A_{Cu}=63.5g/mole$$ The specific resistivity of gold is $$\rho=22.8n\Omega m$$ and the Nordheim coefficient is $$C=450n\Omega m$$
Then by the Nordheim rule we have that the resistivity of this alloy is given as
$$ \rho=\rho _{Au}+CX(1-X)$$
where $X=0.1$, and represents the percentage of Copper in the alloy. 
Using the above I got that 
$$ \rho=63.3 n\Omega m$$, but data shows that the actual resistivity is $ \rho=108 n\Omega m$. What about X? Is it the percentage of atoms in the alloy, or is it the percentage of mass in the alloy?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resistivity is dependent on the number of atoms and so you must find the ratio of copper atoms to the total number of atoms to find $X$ and hence the resistivity of the alloy.
If you do this correctly you should find that the value you have calculated is in agreement with the book value.

---

**Update**

The molar fraction of copper (fraction of copper atoms to the copper and gold atoms) is given by

$X =  \dfrac{\left( \dfrac{10}{63.5} \right)}{\left( \dfrac{10}{63.5}+\dfrac{90}{197} \right)} = \dfrac{394}{1537}$

This comes from the idea that 10 g of copper is $\dfrac{10}{63.2}$ moles of copper which is $\dfrac{10}{63.2} \times N_{\rm A}$ atoms of copper where $N_{\rm A}$ is Avagadro's constant.

$\rho = 22.8 + 450 \times \dfrac{394}{1537} \left ( 1 - \dfrac{394}{1537}\right ) = 108.6$

Comment: I think *to find C* must be a typo because C is a given constant. It should be  *to find X*, which is the mole fraction of Cu atoms.

Comment: What does mole fraction mean?

Answer (score -1):

An accurate physical theory of the electrical resistivity of metal alloys does not exist as of year 2017. I am planning to develop one in 2018.
So, there is no answer to your question, yet.

Comment: Whatever it is that you're smoking, I want some of it.